# Slideshow - continuous loop

Tags: javascript

any help with this would be greatfully appreciated!

I'm trying to implement the script from:

[www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-creating-a-slideshow](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-creating-a-slideshow)

but I would like it to loop continuously, I've managed to get it to loop back and forth:

```
 var totalSlides = 0;
 var currentSlide = 1;
 var contentSlides = "";

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#slideshow-previous").click(showPreviousSlide);
   $("#slideshow-next").click(showNextSlide);

   var totalWidth = 0;
   contentSlides = $(".slideshow-content");
   contentSlides.each(function(i){
     totalWidth += this.clientWidth;
     totalSlides++;
   });
   $("#slideshow-holder").width(totalWidth);
   $("#slideshow-scroller").attr({scrollLeft: 0});
   updateButtons();
 });

function showPreviousSlide()
{
  currentSlide--;
  if (currentSlide < 1) currentSlide = totalSlides;
  updateContentHolder();
  updateButtons();
 }

 function showNextSlide()
 {
   currentSlide++;
   if (currentSlide > totalSlides) currentSlide = 1;
   updateContentHolder();
   updateButtons();
 }

 function updateContentHolder()
 {
   var scrollAmount = 0;
   contentSlides.each(function(i){
     if(currentSlide - 1 > i) {
       scrollAmount += this.clientWidth;
     }
  });
  $("#slideshow-scroller").animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 1000);
 }

 function updateButtons()
 {
 if(currentSlide < totalSlides) {
   $("#slideshow-next").show();}

 if(currentSlide > 1) {
   $("#slideshow-previous").show();}
 }
```

I've been looking at this for 2 nights now and can't work it out.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a preexisting jQuery plugin that does this? There are a **ton** out there. For starters: [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/), [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/), [jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)...

Answer (score 1):

Dave,
  the reason that the slideshow 'ping-pongs' is that

$("#slideshow-scroller").animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 1000);

just points back to the original position when you hit the ends, and so animates back there.

Try This:

css changes thusly

```
.slideshow-content {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;  
}
```

javascript changes thusly

```
// it's nice to work with 0 indexed counters
var totalSlides = -1; 
var currentSlide = 0;
var contentSlides = "";

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#slideshow-previous").click(showPreviousSlide);
   $("#slideshow-next").click(showNextSlide);

   var totalWidth = 0;
   contentSlides = $(".slideshow-content");
   contentSlides.each(function(i){
     totalSlides++;
     //each element is hidden until needed
     $(this).css('left', -100000);  
   });

   //set the position of the first slide
   $(contentSlides[0]).css('left', 0);  

   updateButtons();
 });

function showPreviousSlide()
{
  updateSlides( -1 );
  currentSlide--;
  if (currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = totalSlides; 
  updateButtons();
 }

 function showNextSlide()
 {
   updateSlides( 1 );
   currentSlide++;
   if (currentSlide > totalSlides) currentSlide = 0;   
   updateButtons();
 }

 function updateSlides( direction )
 {
    var scrollAmount = 0;

    var currSlideObj = contentSlides[ currentSlide ];       
    var nextSlideObj = contentSlides[ getNextSlide( direction ) ];

    $( contentSlides ).each( function(){
        if ( this != currSlideObj && this != nextSlideObj ) {
            //each element is hidden until needed
            $(this).css('left', -100000);   
        }
    });

    if ( direction > 0 ) {
        //set the position of the next slide when 'next' pushed
        $( nextSlideObj ).css('left', parseInt($( currSlideObj ).css('left')) + $( currSlideObj ).width());
        //set the amount to animate
        scrollAmount = parseInt($( currSlideObj ).css('left')) - $( currSlideObj ).width();
    } else {
        //set the position of the next slide when 'previous' pushed
        $( nextSlideObj ).css('left', parseInt($( currSlideObj ).css('left')) - $( nextSlideObj ).width());
        //set the amount to animate
        scrollAmount = parseInt($( currSlideObj ).css('left')) + $( currSlideObj ).width();
    }

    // we'll animate the slide objects independently
    $( currSlideObj ).animate({left: scrollAmount}, 1000);
    $( nextSlideObj ).animate({left: 0}, 1000); 

 }

 function getNextSlide( direction ) 
 {
    if ( ( currentSlide + direction ) > totalSlides ) {
        return 0;
    } else if ( ( currentSlide + direction ) < 0 ) {
        return totalSlides;     
    }

    return  currentSlide + direction;

 }

 function updateButtons()
 {
 if(currentSlide < totalSlides) {
   $("#slideshow-next").show();}

 if(currentSlide > 0) {
   $("#slideshow-previous").show();}
 }
```

**Here is how it works:**

each element is hidden offscreen until it's needed.

when a button is pressed,

the two images that must move together are identified.

their positions are set, and all others are hidden offscreen again.

they are animated to new positions.

I also transformed most of your index tests so that they would be zero-based, which is how most modern languages like to interpret collection indexes.

FYI, I expected totalSlides to increment to 2, but it increments to 3,
so setting it to -1 feels hacky - probably a different looping structure is
called for or something.

also, caveat emptor - I haven't tested this on anything but Firefox, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you both soooo much for responding to my post. Almost there - ajaxalex - your solution worked brilliantly. However I have multiple "slides" on my page. The slideshow area is 100% the width on the window so I need to have at least 3 or 4 in view at any one time, any ideas?

Comment: well, this solution isn't optimized for multiple slides, but the brute force way would be to replicate the pattern of 'currentSlideObj' and 'nextSlideObj' with others ( as many as are needed to fill the screen ), and repeat the animate command for as many as you have.

Comment: @Dave if @ajaxlex answered your question, you should accept the answer. If you have ANOTHER question, don't punish @ajaxlex by not accepting here... instead, ask another question.

Comment: Sorry @ajaxlex, @rockinthesixstring has showed me the error of my ways! - What you suggested worked, but I had some inconsistent/unpredictable results so decided that I would go with a different carousel! Thanks again for your help and patience!!

Comment: Hi Dave - If you select the check box ( to the left of my answer, I believe ) then I'll get credit, and will be inspired to do more good deeds throughout the cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create something similar from scratch working with ExtJS for which I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070476/extjs-animation-show-fade-elements-ad-infinitum) which contains the JavaScript source code I ended up using, but ultimately it was based on [jquery.slideShow](https://github.com/Ephigenia/jquery.slideShow) by [Marcel Eichner](http://www.marceleichner.de/). It turned out to be reasonably easy to 'roll-my-own', so to speak, but there are plenty of jQuery options out there for you to try.

Hope this helps!